# What acts in the role of the 'main method' in a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

Servlet is also java program but there is no main method in servlet.Who will take role of main method on servet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Servlets are designed to run inside a servlet container (eg. Apache Tomcat). Execution of a servlet happens in the following manner: The servlet container calls the [`GenericServlet.service()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) method on a servlet which typically calls the appropriate `doXxx()` method, eg. [`doGet()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)), [`doPost()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)), etc. The `doXxx()` method is responsible for interpreting the HTTP request and serving an appropriate response. [`GenericServlet.service()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) is roughly analagous to `main()` in a plain old java class.

Comment: .. and during startup the servlet container does `HttpServlet servletName = new ServletClass();` based on the `web.xml` or the `@WebServlet` and stores it in memory. Whenever the configured `url-pattern` matches the servlet's one, then the `service()` method will be invoked on the particular instance.

Answer (score 5):

Servlet runs inside a container(eg:tomcat). This container perform its work under jvm.
Here container takes "the absence of main method". In simlple java program main method tells 
the starting control flow of the execution. But in case of servlet base web application jvm dose not need to search the main method. Servlet container tells jvm about the starting
control flow.

Comment: Servlet container creates object of specific servlet depending on request url and initializes it by providing config/context objects and then executes it's service method (or doXXX depends on calling HTTP method)

Answer (score 2):

Servlet are deployed on Java application server (servlet container). They are kind of 'passive'. When you write servlet, your servlet code is called by the container whenever there's request or need. So you don't see 'main' in your servlet (the whole thing is not started from servlet), which is inside application server (you could imagine the startup of application server starts from some kind of main).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an area in a servlet to place code that's run on startup (similar to main()), take a look at implementing the [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface.

Its two methods are called on application startup and shutdown.

Comment: @jbruce - that is hardly equivalent to main, IMO.

Comment: @Stephen - I assumed the question was asked with a need to do some coding like you would in a main() method (such as initializations,connections, etc.), I realize my answer doesn't really reflect this so I elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no main method in a Java servlet any more than than an ActionListener on a Swing JButton has a main method. What they both do have are methods that you can hook into when a certain event happens (a click on the JButton for example, or an HTTP PUT request on a HttpServlet). And in both cases, you are provided information about the event that triggered the call - the ActionEvent for the JButton and the ServletRequest for a servlet.

Thinking of servlets in terms of event handlers is probably more useful than trying to think of them like a standalone Java application where you are responsible for the entire control flow.